# Gson Exception on deserialize (no-args constructor does not exist)

Tags: android, json, exception, gson

I've got a problem which occurs only in 10 of 5000 devices. There is no possibility to reproduce it with my emulators and test devices. It seems to be a very specific problem with only a few devices. All I've got is the stacktrace and my code. So I'm developing against a black hole and only after I released the new version at GooglePlay I see if the changes solved the problem. I just updated a new version to GooglePlay, but the error still exists.

The changes were parameterless contructors and change the WorkIem [class to static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148011/android-and-gson-throwing-no-args-constructor-not-found-exception).

Here is the stacktrace:

```
W 6758/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x401a15a0)
E 6758/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No-args constructor for class com.mypackage.model.UpdaterObject$UpdateReport does not exist. Register an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type to fix this problem.**
    at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.constructWithNoArgConstructor(MappedObjectConstructor.java:64)
    at com.google.gson.MappedObjectConstructor.construct(MappedObjectConstructor.java:53)
    at com.google.gson.JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.constructTarget(JsonObjectDeserializationVisitor.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationVisitor.getTarget(JsonDeserializationVisitor.java:56)
    at com.google.gson.ObjectNavigator.accept(ObjectNavigator.java:109)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.fromJsonObject(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:73)
    at com.google.gson.JsonDeserializationContextDefault.deserialize(JsonDeserializationContextDefault.java:51)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:568)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:515)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:484)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:434)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:406)
    **at de.fliese.NewVersionCheckerActivity.onCreate(NewVersionCheckerActivity.java:35)**
```

This is line 35:

```
UpdateReport report = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, UpdateReport.class);
```

The json-String looks like this (Workitems can be null):

```
{"WorkItems":
[{"Url":"http://url1.comfoo.zip","TypeId":1,"LastModifiedServer":1352598239000},
{"Url":"http://url2.com/bar.zip","TypeId":4,"LastModifiedServer":1352598265000}],
 "ShowQuestionDialog":false,"IsOffline":false,"DoUpdate":true}
```

And finally here is my UpdateReport class with the innerClass:

```
public class UpdaterObject{     
public class UpdateReport {

            public boolean IsOffline;
            public boolean DoUpdate;
            public boolean ShowQuestionDialog;
            public List<WorkItem> WorkItems;

            public UpdateReport() {        }

            public UpdateReport(boolean isoffline, boolean doUpdate,
                    List<WorkItem> workitems) {
                IsOffline = isoffline;
                DoUpdate = doUpdate;
                WorkItems = workitems;
            }
        }

        public static class WorkItem {

            public int TypeId;
            public String Url;
            public long LastModifiedServer;

            public WorkItem() {        }

            public WorkItem(int typeId, String url, long lastModifiedServer) {
                TypeId = typeId;
                Url = url;
                LastModifiedServer = lastModifiedServer;
            }
        }
    //some methods [....]
    } //end class UpdaterObject
```

I would be happy, if someone could help me. Please make sure and be sure that your answer ist absolutely correct, because I can't test it! That would be great!

This is my first posting on StackOverFlow. Please be fair. :)

Thanks qd0r

Comment: Question about TypeId: are you sure about `int` type?

Comment: I strongly recommend to override Exception and add Device/Manufacture info, Android version ... on each Exception drop. It will help you to diagnose the issues.

Comment: Yes, TypeId is int. 
good idea! now I created 3 classes:
WorkItem and UpdateReport for the model and the (renamed) UpdaterObject for getters which returns an UpdateReport object. All classes got a empty default constructor now. I hope that solves the problem.

Comment: Sometimes you can get GSON data with `null` parameters and on *casting* to primitive value causes to `JsonDeserializationContextDefault` problem.

Comment: You're using an obsolete version of Gson. Please upgrade to the latest.

Comment: @JesseWilson thats not true. i'm using the latest version 2.2.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Gson issue 255](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255), The HTC Desire HD included an obsolete copy of Gson in its application classpath. That issue has instructions on using jarjar to repackage your version of Gson as to not conflict with the preinstalled version.

Comment: WOW! This answer looks really helpful. Now I got the information, that my app has problems with HTC Desire HD and HTC Explorer.

Comment: thanks @jesse wilson!
problem fixed! here the solution (http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/issues/detail?id=255):
1) Download jarjar (http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/downloads/list)
2) Put jarjar-1.0.jar and gson-1.5.jar in the same folder
3) Create a new text file in this folder (rules.txt)
4) Write the following line in the textfile: rule com.google.gson.** com.google.myjson.@1
5) From the commandline, open jarjar with the command "java -jar jarjar.jar process rules.txt gson-1.5.jar myjson-1.5.jar"
6) Replace the gson library in your project with myjson and update the imports

Comment: important additional note: if you use proguard, don't forget to change the rules for the gson-library. ;)

Comment: +1 - that's a lot of time saved. Just had this reported in Play. I'm tempted not to perform this fix for making my life just that little bit more convoluted in the future. Another reason to drop Gingerbread IMO. Is it likely that people like HTC will make this sort of error again? Has Google berated them good for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case proguard was the problem. Disable proguard or put your model in proguard rules file. Worked for me.